# Inheritance can't access map

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary

I cannot seem to access the map in the parent class from the child class, as I try to output the contents of the map and nothing is displayed.

BELOW I HAVE ADDED IN THE FULL CODE, OVERALL IF I POPULATE THE MAP IN THE transLateMask() it will then print out the contents, however if i populate the map in the populate() it will print out nothing and I do not know why?

Here is my code.

```
//HEADER FILE
//////PARENT CLASS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct TTYElementBase 
{
    //some code here
};

class element
{
    public:
    std::map<char,std::string> transMask;
    std::map<char,std::string>::iterator it;
    void populate();
};

//////CHILD CLASS .HPP

class elementV : public element
{
    public :
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    elementV();
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, const elementV &);
    void transLateMask();
};

//CPP FILE #include "example.h"

elementV::elementV()
{
}

void element::populate()
 {
    transMask['D']='D'; //WILL PRINT OUT NOTHING IF I POPULATE HERE 

 }


void elementV::transLateMask()
{

    for ( it=transMask.begin() ; it != transMask.end(); it++ )
        std::cout << (*it).first << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    element e;
    e.populate();
    elementV v;
    v.transLateMask();
}
```

It doesn't output anything - why is that?

Comment: You're not putting anything in those maps in the code you posted.

Comment: Works as documented, not as expected...

Comment: UPDATED CODE `transMask['D']='D';

  for ( it=transMask.begin() ; it != transMask.end(); it++ )
   cout << (*it).first << "->" << (*it).second<< endl;` but for **<< (*it).second<< endl;** it says **no operater << matches these operands** does that mean i have to overload them? but iof it works for the first character in the map why not the second? @Mat

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: your code cannot compile as is, what you posted is missing `std::` qualifiers on `cout` and `endl`. As already said, you're not filling the maps, so no output is the expected behavior. Please edit your question to put code that actually reproduces your issue.

Comment: yes thats it in **element class** i have a method called  **populate** if  insert those elements in that method and not the **transLateMask()** there is no output why @KerekSB

Comment: @Mat i have editted my question could you please take a look, ask me any questions if you are unsure :)

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: where are you calling `populate`?

Comment: ah i missed it out there on accident but i was calling it in the main before `transLateMask()` and the output was nothin @Mat

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: I repeat myself: please post a piece of code that 1. compiles, and 2. reproduces your problem.

Comment: @Mat full piece of code above compiles and reproduces my problem (No Output)

Comment: Why does your second paragraph yell?

Comment: All caps is yelling. SO offers markup like bold and italics if you'd like to emphasize something, but use it sparingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to e.populate() populates e.transMask, not v.transMask. You need to call v.populate().

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have the include directive `#include <string>`.

Comment: The code would completely fail to compile if `<string>` wasn't included directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Mat, from his comment **no operater << matches these operands** I think that is the case.

Comment: @Mat ok yeah so full piece of code has been posted above

Answer (score 0):

Also replace the `#include <string.hpp>` with `#include <string>`

Than optionally you can add the `using namespace std;` so you don't have to use the `std::` qualifiers all over the palce